# Directive scope attributes break depending on attribute name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a very strange phenomenon with a directive and an isolated scope, where the attributes in the scope work or do not work depending on the naming of the attribute. If I use

```
{check:'@check'}
```

it works just fine and as expected. However,if I use:

```
{checkN:'@checkN'}
```

the defined function never gets assigned. An example would look like:

**HTML:**

```
<item ng-repeat="list_item in model.list" model="list_item" checkN="checkName()" check="checkName()" position="$index"></item>'
```

**Javascript**

```
app.directive('item', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace : false,   
      scope:{
              $index: '=position',
              check: '&check',
              checkN: '&checkN',
              model:'='
      },          
      template: '',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log(scope.check())
        console.log(scope.checkN())          
      }
    }
});
```

The console will then give me the following:

```
The checkName function has been called [which is the return string of the function]
undefined
```

It is really possible that it depends on the usage of capital letters? This would be very "unexpected" behaviour.

Thanks for your help

schacki

Comment: "Directives have camel cased names such as `ngBind`. The directive can be invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these special characters `:`, `-`, or `_`. Optionally the directive can be prefixed with `x-`, or `data-` to make it HTML validator compliant." -- [Directive page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) section "Invoking directives from HTML"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Html is case insensitive, therefore `myAttribute` and `myattribute` would be indistinguishable from each other depending on the browser. Angularjs' authors made a design decision about passing from html to javascript and vice-versa in terms of directives.

`ngRepeat` directive would be used as `ng-repeat` in the view(html). 
Likewise, your directive `checkN` should be used as `check-n` for angular to recognise that as directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The angular team has documented it clearly for directives. But following the docs, I had not expected the same behavior here.

Comment: @schacki Exactly -- in my case I had attribute names that started with an acronym -- e.g. DNSHost="myhost", and Angular *silently ignored them* without any possible translation. The documentation says nothing about that. Just wasted 2 hours :(